# I am not able to find how previous team routed redis dump.rdb to store in different directory , it is not storing in /var/lib/redis

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I am quite familiar with redis conf files, I also aware that by default redis stores dump.rdb files under /var/lib/redis

I transitioned to handle app where previous team installed redis in /opt/app/, also I see dump.rdb files present in /var/lib/redis but it is not storing anything and date stamp is 2 years old. Now I found that redis storing dump.rdb in different location but I am not able to find that location specified in redis.conf file, Is there any other file where dump.rdb location could be specified that tells redis to store dump.rdb to specific location?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `config get dir` and `config get dbfilename` to get the path and filename of current RDB file. You can also use `config set dir xxx` and `config set dbfilename xxx` to dynamically change the path and filename.

Also you can use the `info server` command to get the path of config file your Redis instance is loading (check the `config_file` item)

Comment: I see that dump.conf file has variable dir <path of dump> which is the location. Got it. I guess I missed that part in rush.